# Export JavaScript Formatting in Netbeans

Tags: javascript, netbeans, code-formatting

Is anyone aware of a way to export the formatting for JavaScript in Netbeans 8.1?

When I click the **export** button and expand *Formatting* I do not see an option for JavaScript.

[image: Screenshot of options]

I've also considered the option of finding the file that these settings are stored in and using that, but I'm not sure where in the Netbeans folder it would be.

Thank you for any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to track down the file *org-netbeans-modules-editor-settings-CustomPreferences.xml* at the location **\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.1\config\Editors\text\javascript\Preferences**. I gave this file to a coworker who placed it in the same directory and restarted the IDE which resulted in the same formatting settings that I had originally configured for mine. So the solution was to just share the file.

Hope this helps someone out in the future.